# Convert "weekday, month day, year - hh:mm:ss" to "dd/mm/yyyy"

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have downloaded some data from a booking website for my listing as a .csv file. An example of the format of reservation dates is: "Wednesday, January 24, 2018 - 08:59:49".

I would like to convert this in Excel to a simple "dd/mm/yyyy" format (in the example: "24/01/2018").

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to extract the date from that cell.
If the text is in A1 then

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1,1)-1+FIND(",",A1,1)))
```

Then format your cell accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

if all your value are in the above format("Wednesday, January 24, 2018 - 08:59:49".), below formula should work fine

`=TEXT(TRIM(MID(F24,FIND(",",F24,1)+2,FIND("-",F24,1)-12)),"dd/mm/yyyy")`

change the cell range accordingly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
=TEXT(MID(A1,(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1)+1),(FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1))-(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1)+1)) & "/" & MID(A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+2,(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1))-(FIND(" ",A1,1)+1)) & "/" & MID(A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1)+2,((FIND("-",A1,1))-(FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1))-3)),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```